# How to iteratively search regex column names and if a match is there add to list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

imagine you have the following df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['d','d','deda'],['t','f','r'],['r','t','y']],
                  columns=['d','t','didi'])
```

and the following list:

```
listkeep = ["Access Risk ID",'User Group', 'User Name','Condition record no.', 'Created By', 'User ID', 'Purchasing Document', 'Article', 'Created By', 'Condition record no.']
```

I would like to add each column/value of the df that contains a 'd' to the list as a string.

desired output

```
listkeep = ["Access Risk ID",'User Group', 'User Name','Condition record no.', 'Created By', 'User ID', 'Purchasing Document', 'Article', 'Created By', 'Condition record no.', 'd', 'didi', 'd','d','deda']
```

how would I do this iteratively for 10 DFs that each contain different column values? I tried something like this but did not work:

```
    for i, column in df.columns:
        if column in df.filter(regex=(str((df['tabel_id_links'][i])|CTA['tabel_id_rechts'][i]))).columns[i]:
            listkeep.append(column)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use simple list comprehensions:

```
query = 'd'

# column names
l1 = [c for c in df.columns if query in c]
# or
# l1 = list(df.filter(like=query).columns)

# dataframe values
l2 = [v for v in df.stack() if query in v]
# or
# s = df.stack()
# l2 = list(s[s.str.contains(query)])

listkeep.extend(l1+l2)

print(listkeep)
```

*NB. you don't actually need the l1/l2 variables used here for clarity, you can directly `extend`:*

```
listkeep.extend([c for c in df.columns if query in c])
listkeep.extend([v for v in df.stack() if query in v])
```

output:

```
['Access Risk ID',
 'User Group',
 'User Name',
 'Condition record no.',
 'Created By',
 'User ID',
 'Purchasing Document',
 'Article',
 'Created By',
 'Condition record no.',
 'd',
 'didi',
 'd',
 'd',
 'deda']
```

Comment: Thanks Mozway, do you have an idea how to set the query iteratively based on a different column value?

Comment: can you provide an example?